# Get all matches for a certain pattern using RegEx

Tags: regex

I am not really a RegEx expert and hence asking a simple question.

I have a few parameters that I need to use which are in a particular pattern
For example

```
$$DATA_START_TIME
$$DATA_END_TIME
$$MIN_POID_ID_DLAY
$$MAX_POID_ID_DLAY
$$MIN_POID_ID_RELTM
$$MAX_POID_ID_RELTM
```

And these will be replaced at runtime in a string with their values (a SQL statement).

For example I have a simple query

```
select * from asdf where asdf.starttime = $$DATA_START_TIME and asdf.endtime = $$DATA_END_TIME
```

Now when I try to use the RegEx pattern

```
\$\$[^\W+]\w+$
```

I do not get all the matches(I get only a the last match).

I am trying to test my usage here https://regex101.com/r/xR9dG0/2

If someone could correct my mistake, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you in? Getting rid of the `$` and using the `g` modifier seems to do the trick. https://regex101.com/r/vP3kV8/1

Comment: its c# which I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
\$\$\w+/g
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ4aM9/1)

Just Some clarifications why your regex is doing what is doing:

```
\$\$[^\W+]\w+$
```

Unescaped $ char means end of string, so, your pattern is matching something that must be on the end of the string, that's why its getting only the last match.

This group `[^\W+]` doesn't really makes sense, groups starting with [^..] means negate the chars inside here, and \W is the negation of words, and + inside the group means literally the char +, so you are saying match everything that is Not a Not word and that is not a + sign, i guess that was not what you wanted.

To match the next word just \w+ will do it. And the global modifier `/g` ensures that you will not stop on the first match.

Comment: Didnt know it was that simple. I am writing a query engine which uses these parameters. These parameters come from Informatica config file and I need to pass these on to my engine which will replace the values at run time and execute the query,

Answer (score 0):

This should work -  Based on what you said you wanted to match this should work . Also it won't match $$lower_case_strings if that's what you wanted. If not, add the "i" flag also.

```
\${2}[A-Z_]+/g
```